# multiple row & column collectionview lagging and not working smoothly as expected

Tags: ios, objective-c, layout, uicollectionview

I have implemented Row & Column based `CollectionView` and enabled it with `customlayout` of `UICollectionView` and it's working fine as expected with fixed `width` & `height` of Row & Column.

But unfortunately, it's not working smoothly with dynamic `width` & `height` of Row & Column.

Below is screenshot of fixed height & width output of `CollectionView` :
[image]

**I used the below code to Achieve the above dynamic custom layout:**

```
- (void)prepareLayout {
    [super prepareLayout];
    self.gridRowCount = [self.collectionView numberOfSections];
    self.gridColumnCount = [self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:0];

    if (!self.isInitialized) {
        id<UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout> delegate = (id)self.collectionView.delegate;
        CGSize size = [delegate collectionView:self.collectionView
                                        layout:self
                        sizeForItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0]];
        self.itemSize = size;
        self.isInitialized = YES;
    }
}


- (CGSize)collectionViewContentSize {
    if (!self.isInitialized) {
        [self prepareLayout];
    }
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(self.gridColumnCount * self.itemSize.width, self.gridRowCount * self.itemSize.height);
    return size;
}

- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    NSMutableArray *attributes = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSUInteger startRow = floorf(rect.origin.y / self.itemSize.height);
    NSUInteger startCol = floorf(rect.origin.x / self.itemSize.width);
    NSUInteger endRow = MIN(self.gridRowCount - 1, ceilf(CGRectGetMaxY(rect) / self.itemSize.height));
    NSUInteger endCol = MIN(self.gridColumnCount - 1, ceilf(CGRectGetMaxX(rect) / self.itemSize.width));
    NSParameterAssert(self.gridRowCount > 0);
    NSParameterAssert(self.gridColumnCount > 0);
    
    for (NSUInteger row = startRow; row <= endRow; row++) {
        for (NSUInteger col = startCol; col <=  endCol; col++) {
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:col inSection:row];
            UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *layoutAttributes = [self layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            [attributes addObject:layoutAttributes];
        }
    }
    return attributes;
}

- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes layoutAttributesForCellWithIndexPath:indexPath];
    attributes.frame = CGRectMake(indexPath.item * self.itemSize.width, indexPath.section * self.itemSize.height, self.itemSize.width-self.cellSpacing, self.itemSize.height-self.cellSpacing);
    return attributes;
}

- (BOOL)shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:(CGRect)newBounds {
    return NO;
}
```

I want the dynamic size of the cell and column and it will not leg at all and scroll smoothly.

**Note:** I have more than 200K records to display in this `CollectionView`. It's working without any lagging with 2K rows but after that, it's taking time to layout rows & columns.

Comment: Set auto layout for your UICollectionViewCell xib.

Comment: I have already tried but still its not scrolling smoothly.

Comment: You are making datasource of CollectionView for all the 2 lakh records at once?

Comment: yes I am passing whole data which i got from server to `CollectionView` `datasource`.